# CSS width transition from 0 to x causes content squish

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/323qLz0y/

```js
$('.middle-panel').on('mouseover', function() {
  $('.left-panel').addClass('left-panel-slide');
  $('.container').addClass('container-slide');
});

$('.middle-panel').on('mouseout', function() {
  $('.left-panel').removeClass('left-panel-slide');
  $('.container').removeClass('container-slide');
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px blue solid;
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  left: 300px;
  top: 30%;
  transition: width 1s, left 1s;
}

.container-slide {
  width: 400px;
  left: 100px;
}

.middle-panel {
  background: grey;
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  float: left;
}

.left-panel {
  width: 0px;
  transition: width 1s;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 250px;
}

.left-panel-slide {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-panel">
    <h1> Hello World! </h1>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ea vero veritus eam, ad aperiri inermis consequuntur est. Id mundi accumsan eum, ius modo dicunt quaerendum ex.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="middle-panel"></div>
</div>
```

Hover over the grey box. See how when the left panel slides out, the content is squished vertically? When the transition ends, the content becomes "well-formed". How can i make the content "well-formed" while it is sliding out? Thanks.

Stack requires some code so here's the left panel portion. I tried `white-space:nowrap` but it forces the content onto one line which isn't what i want.

```
.left-panel {
width: 0px;
transition: width 1s;
float:left;
overflow: hidden;
height: 250px;
}
.left-panel-slide {
    width:200px;
}
```

Comment: See my answer for a simpler no-JavaScript solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply give width to the `p` and `h1` to achieve the effect you are looking for

```js
$('.middle-panel').on('mouseover', function () {
    $('.left-panel').addClass('left-panel-slide');
    $('.container').addClass('container-slide');
});

$('.middle-panel').on('mouseout', function () {
    $('.left-panel').removeClass('left-panel-slide');
    $('.container').removeClass('container-slide');
});
```

```css
.container {
    position: absolute;
    border: 3px blue solid;
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    left: 300px;
    top:30%;
    transition: width 1s, left 1s;
}
.container-slide {
    width: 400px;
    left:100px;
}
.middle-panel {
    background:grey;
    width:200px;
    height: 250px;
    float:left;
}
.left-panel {
    width: 0px;
    transition: width 1s;
    float:left;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 250px;
}
.left-panel p,.left-panel h1{
    width:200px;
}
.left-panel-slide {
    width:200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="left-panel">
         <h1> Hello World! </h1>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ea vero veritus eam, ad aperiri inermis consequuntur est. Id mundi accumsan eum, ius modo dicunt quaerendum ex.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="middle-panel"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, a super simple answer that works. Just what i needed, thanks! Will accept answer when SO lets me.

Comment: Glad i could help @EricGuan

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the content that slides inside a div with a fixed width.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="left-panel">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <h1> Hello World! </h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ea vero veritus eam, ad aperiri inermis consequuntur est. Id mundi accumsan eum, ius modo dicunt quaerendum ex.</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="middle-panel"></div>
</div>

.content-wrapper {
 width: 200px;
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/323qLz0y/

Answer (score 0):

You have to fix children's width, like this (refering to the JS fiddle HTML):

```
.left-panel h1, .left-panel p{
   width: 200px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is all very doable without JavaScript or extra styling on the inner elements.

```css
.container {
    position: absolute;
    border: 3px blue solid;
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    left: 300px;
    top:30%;
    transition: width 1s, left 1s;
}
.middle-panel {
    background:grey;
    width:200px;
    height: 250px;
    float:left;
}
.left-panel {
    width: 180px;
    padding: 10px;
    transition: all 1s;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 250px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
.container:hover .left-panel {
    left: -200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-panel">
    <h1> Hello World! </h1>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ea vero veritus eam, ad aperiri inermis consequuntur est. Id mundi accumsan eum, ius modo dicunt quaerendum ex.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="middle-panel"></div>
</div>
```

**[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/323qLz0y/2/)**